# How to configure Django to access remote MySQL db django.contrib.sites.RequestSite module missing

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to set up a django app that connects to a remote MySQL db. I currently have Django==1.10 and MySQL-python==1.2.5 installed in my venv. In settings.py I have added the following to the DATABASES variable:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'db_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
    'HOST': 'db_host',
    'PORT': 'db_port',
}
```

I get the error

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
```

when I run python manage.py migrate

I am a complete beginner when it comes to django. Is there some step I am missing?

edit: I have also installed mysql-connector-c via brew install
edit2: realized I just need to connect to a db by importing MySQLdb into a file. sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi, could you explain a little bit more what exactly you did? `python manage.py makemigrations` should be IMHO executed before `migrate`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the relevant info to tell you would be to be honest. When I run makemigrations, I get a similar error saying that RequestSite cannot be found. I have also included 'django.contrib.sites' into the installed app section of settings.py

Comment: do I need to write models in models.py that mimic the structure of the db I'm trying to connect to?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. The remote database is the one for the django app where it stores its data? Or is it an already existing database used by your app to read some data?

Comment: I am trying to connect to an existing mysql database not create the database with django

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now. I would recommend giving up the Django database system and just set up your own connection using pure Python. Maybe it is possible to connect with Django, but I find this way easier.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing has nothing to do with your database settings (assuming your real code has the actual database name, username, and password) or connection. You are not importing the RequestSite from the correct spot.

Change (wherever you have this set) from:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
```

to:

```
from django.contrib.sites.requests import RequestSite
```

Answer (score 0):

This is documentation you should look at this for connecting to databases and how django does it, from what you gave us, as long as your parameters are correct you should be connecting to the database but a good confirmation of this would be the inspectdb tool.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/

This shows you how to import your models from the sql database:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/

To answer your question in the comments

"
Auto-generate the models

Django comes with a utility called inspectdb that can create models by introspecting an existing database. You can view the output by running this command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Save this as a file by using standard Unix output redirection:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

"